# Import MDB in ZIP as ASSOCIATION

Tags: import, databases, compression

I have a zip file which contains an access database file (mdb format). How do I extract the database and the headers and convert them to association format? I know the command for doing that separately if the file is not compressed. However, considering the zipped file is only 1mb and the extracted file is 28mb, there is a lot of disk space saved if I keep the zip file on disk (The size is only 1 file, there are probably thousands of these zips).

Comment: I don't know the answer off-hand, but at least when the file is gzip-compressed, then decompression is usually transparent.  Maybe you can try using gzip instead of zip.  (I'm not saying it's not possible with zip too. I simply don't know.)

Comment: I think I found the solution, just do a normal database import and put a `"*.mdb"` as level one parameter. mathematica supports all basic compressed formats.

Comment: I urge you to write up your solution as a self-answer.